# Access Violation with HashTable

Tags: c++, pointers, hashtable, access-violation, nullptr

I was given an assignment to create a hash table that contains 30 buckets (20 primary, and 10 overflow), with each bucket containing 3 slots (each slot containing 2 stings for key and data passed in), a counter integer and a pointer variable that points to the next overflow bucket. My last C++ class was over a year ago so I'm completely lost as to how I am supposed to create this table properly (with no help from my professor).

This is my class declaration below. It technically compiles, however it crashes immediately, and when it debugs, I get an "Access Violation Reading Location" error stating "this was nullptr" on my home computer (and it includes a specific memory location on the computer I used in class).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Define Global Variables
#define MAXBUCKETs 30
#define MAXSLOTs 3
typedef char STR10[10 + 1];
typedef char STR20[20 + 1];

// Define Class
class hash{

public:

    int primaryBuckets = 20;
    int overflowBuckets = 10;

    union bucket
    {
        int count;
        bucket* nextOverflow;

        struct slot {
            string keyValue;
            string dataValue;
        };

        slot* slots[2];

    } HashTable[30];

    hash();                                         // Initialize HashTable
    int HashFunction(STR10 key, int buckets);       // Hash key to index
    void InsertIntoHT(STR10 key, STR20 data);       // Add data to slot
    void PrintItemsInIndex();
    void InsertOverflow(STR10 key, STR20 data, int index);
    void InsertPrimary(STR10 key, STR20 data, int index);
};
```

My constructor, from what I understand, initialized the array in the right order

```
::hash::hash()
{


    for (int i = 0; i < MAXBUCKETs; i++)
    {
        HashTable[i].count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < MAXSLOTs; j++)
        {
            HashTable[i].slots[j]->keyValue = "no_data";
            HashTable[i].slots[j]->dataValue = "no_data";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty desperate for help at this point. I'm almost certain it's a bad pointer, but I've never understood them well. All help will be greatly appreciated! (This is also my first post so hopefully I didn't do anything wrong)

Comment: `slot* slots[2];` should be `slot* slots[MAXSLOTs];` You used a magic number of 2 then set `MAXSLOTs` to 3. You should avoid these magic numbers..

Comment: Also `HashTable[30];` should be `HashTable[MAXBUCKETs]`

Comment: Sorry to say it, but the code's a mess.  For a start, `union`s are weird things: they can only store one of the listed members at a time: you should use a `struct` instead.  Then, `slots` are pointers - you can't dereference them to access `keyValue` and `dataValue` until you've pointed them at some properly allocated memory: use `new`.

Comment: There is no need to be sorry, it really is a mess. I toyed around with structs however I'm not sure how I can hold 3 slots within a struct. Is it possible to hold 3 slots, a pointer and an int in a struct?

Comment: ***Is it possible to hold 3 slots, a pointer and an int in a struct*** Yes of course.

Comment: You can have any number of members in a struct, as long as memory permits.

Comment: Ok, thank you everybody for your answers, I'm grasping this a little more now. Tony, when you say use new, how would I go about that? Should I make HashTable[i] = new slot; ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand this, but the union looks suspicious

```
union bucket
{
    int count;
    bucket* nextOverflow;

    struct slot {
        string keyValue;
        string dataValue;
    };

    slot* slots[2];

} HashTable[30];
```

A [union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) is supposed to hold only *one* of its members, in this case one of

- count
- nextOverflow
- slots[2]

Maybe a `struct bucket` is more appropriate.

---

Specifically,

```
HashTable[i].count = 0;
```

sets `count` member to zero, and at the same time overwrites memory of `slots`, which holds a pointer to a `slot` entry

```
HashTable[i].slots[j]->keyValue = "no_data";
```

Here you must either use plain `slot` objects, which I recommend, e.g.

```
slot slots[MAXSLOTs];
```

or first initialize with new

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXSLOTs; ++i)
    slots[i] = new slot;
```

Comment: I landed on a union because I figured my original problem was stemming from trying to access my slot struct members from within an array struct pointers. I just changed it back to struct bucket, but I'm now getting an access violation at 0xCCCCCCCC

Comment: Where do you get this access violation? Have you also changed `slots[2]` to `slots[MAXSLOTs]`, because 2 != MAXSLOTs?

Comment: Yes, I have changed slots[2] to MAXSLOTs, and HashTable[30] to HashTable[MAXBUCKETs]. Visual Studio is debugging it and it's not giving me a specific location.

Comment: `0xCCCCCCCC` means uninitialized stack memory. https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892

Comment: Thank you for the help Olaf! I tried to change my "struct slot" to a slot object, but I can't find any resources regarding accessing slot objects. When I tried to create a new slot struct using this: HashTable[i].slots[j] = new slot;  I get a "syntax error: identifier 'slot'"

Comment: There's no need to allocate with `new slot`, when you use objects instead of pointers. Accessing is done with the dot operator `.` instead of `->`, e.g. `HashTable[i].slots[j].keyValue = "no_data";`

Comment: Olaf, you are incredible! Thank you so much for everything, that was exactly what I was doing wrong. I changed to a slot object and used the dot operator and the program runs as it should. I really appreciate your patience and help!

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped.